# Is this bush dying?

Tags: identification, shrubs

I'm not sure what this bush is called, but it appears that one side of it isn't leafing out. Can anybody offer some insight on this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Dying - probably not. Had a bad winter - probably. Half dead and dying are often (not always) different things with plants.

Comment: As for identification-does it flower? If so, can you describe the flowers, or post a picture if you have one? Does anyone here think it's in the weigela family, or are the leaves wrong?

Comment: Having a dry year? Many dryland bushes will partially die back when the weather turns bad. 2nd pic clearly shows some regrowth. So cut out the obviously dead stuff and let it fill in again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this plant is a [Daphne x burkwoodii "Carol Mackie"](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/PlantFinder/PlantFinderDetails.aspx?kempercode=c420).  It's evergreen in many zones, and has small fragrant flowers in the early spring.  It's a very valuable garden plant but can be severely affected by winter cold and especially winds. It also likes even moisture and a partly shady position in your garden.

The good news is that you can cut it back, even severely, in my experience (by as much as 2/3rds), to create new growth in the dead-looking areas. The best time to cut it back is in late spring after it flowers, but you could also do it any time before fall.

It looks like a good-sized, established specimen.  Daphne do not like to be moved, so leave it where it is.

I've really enjoyed having this shrub in my garden - I love the variegated foliage and the sweet-smelling spring flowers.